# reloading the soundcloud html widget with different sets from links

Tags: soundcloud

I was advised to post this here by SoundCloud support - I hope you can help.  I want to use the html5 widget on my site and access different sets but, rather than have multiple widgets on a page, I want to be able to reload the widget with a different set by clicking on different links on the page.  It seems you can do this using the API and I have been playing with w.soundcloud.com/player/api_playground.html and have got it to load my sets by putting the api.soundclound.com url in the appropriate box and clicking "reload widget".

I really don’t know javascript at all so I was hoping to copy the source from that page and try and edit it to do what I want.  However, I can’t even get the page to load when it is hosted on my site:

http://www.indigomusic.co.uk/SCtest/playground.htm

I downloaded api.js and put it in a folder on my server but I’m obviously missing step(s).  I’ve read http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/html5-widget#introduction but it obviously assumes a level of javascript knowledge that I just don’t have...

...are you able to help?

Many thanks,

Dan Selby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have do use the Widget API for that necessarily.
Here is a simple example using jQuery and the SoundCloud SDK doing what you described:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12477597/Temporary/dynamic-widget-example.html

Hope it Helps.

Comment: Just a quick couple of follow up questions: when the page loads there is no player widget loaded and when you do click a link the player loads *above* the links.

Ideally, I would like that when the page loads the links are at the top and the player loads underneath and autoplays "link1".  If you could point me to what I need to change in your code to do that I would be really grateful - thanks!

Comment: If anyone can help fill in the final piece of the puzzle for me, I would be really grateful!  Johannes solution works really well except that I need the widget to load with the set in link 1 when the page initially loads.  Many thanks.

Comment: This will automatically load the first link:
  $(function(){
    SC.oEmbed($(".soundcloud-link").get(0).attr("href"), {auto_play: true}, $(".player").get(0));
    $(".soundcloud-link").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        SC.oEmbed($(this).attr("href"), {auto_play: true}, $(".player").get(0));
    });
  });